# ¿Cómo obtener el Context 2d que usa la libreria Pica para manejar Canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Necesito borrar el contenido de un canvas. Este canvas tiene una imagen que he puesto usando la libreria Pica de esta forma:

```
    ///setear la imagen
    var img2 = new Image();
    img2.src = img.attr("src");
    img2.width = img[0].naturalWidth;
    img2.height = img[0].naturalHeight;

    //establecer tamaño del canvas
    this.canvas.width = width;
    this.canvas.height = height;

    ///poner la imagen en el canvas
    var promise = pica().resize(img2, this.canvas ,{
        unsharpAmount: 100,
        unsharpRadius: 0,
        unsharpThreshold: 0
    });
```

Esto me devuelve un [object HTMLCanvasElement]

```
promise.then(cavas_x => console.log(`resize done! ${cavas_x }`))
```

Pero yo necesito un [object CanvasRenderingContext2D] para poder borrar el canvas así:

```
clear() 
{
    this.canvas.width = this.canvas.width;      
    this.contexto.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);           
}
```

El contexto de (this.canvas) no me esta funcionando porque pica() está usando otro y es al que intento acceder.

¿Sabría alguien como hacerlo? o ¿Alguna otra forma de borrar la imagen?

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías crear un [mcve]? Ayudaría bastante a intentar reproducir el problema. Gracias.

Comment: claro!! voy a ello!!

Comment: @IvánRodríguez ¿podrias poner ese ejemplo que si funciona como respuesta y aceptarla como válida? creo que así será de más utilidad a futuras visitas.

Comment: Si, claro que si.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EJEMPLO MíNIMO VERIFICABLE

Al hacer este ejemplo mínimo me he dado cuenta de que funciona correctamente y que debo tener alguna cosa en el código original que me impide borrar la imagen. De todas formas voy a dejar esto aquí por si a alguien le ayuda en algo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pica.js"></script>
    <!-- https://github.com/nodeca/pica/blob/master/dist/pica.js -->
</head>
<body>
        <button type="button" id="btn_borrar">Borrar</button>
        <input id="file" type="file"  accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png">
        <img id="img1" width="100" height="100">
        <canvas id="render" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
</html>

<script>

$( document ).ready(function()
{


class Canvas
{
    constructor() 
    {
        this.canvas = $("#render")[0];
        this.getContext();
    }
    getContext() 
    {           
        this.contexto = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    }           

    clear() 
    {
        this.canvas.width = this.canvas.width;      
        this.contexto.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);           
    }

    //carga la imagen el canvas de renderizado
    load(img)
    {           
        if(img.attr("src")==undefined)
            return; 

        this.clear();

        //conseguir tamaño de la imagen y el canvas
        var height=500;//parseInt(this.container.height());
        var width=parseInt(img[0].naturalWidth*height/img[0].naturalHeight);    

        ///setear la imagen
        var img2 = new Image();
        img2.src = img.attr("src");
        img2.width = img[0].naturalWidth;
        img2.height = img[0].naturalHeight;

        //establecer tamaño del canvas
        this.canvas.width = width;
        this.canvas.height = height;                


        ///poner la imagen en el canvas
        var promise = pica().resize(img2, this.canvas ,{
            unsharpAmount: 100,
            unsharpRadius: 0,
            unsharpThreshold: 0
        });

    }
}

c = new Canvas();

$("#file").change(function(e) 
{

    var imgObj = e.target.files[0]; 

    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL;
    imgObj.src = url.createObjectURL(imgObj);

    $("#img1").attr("src",imgObj.src); 
    $("#file").val("")
});

$("#img1").on("load", function(e)
{
    c.load($(this));
});       



$("#btn_borrar").on("click", function(e)
{
    c.clear();

});

});



</script>
```